# Retrieve Joomla's Session in external PHP

Tags: php, joomla1.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing session data outside Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175598/accessing-session-data-outside-joomla)

I tried to use the below script to retrieve Joomla's Session, but it's not working.
Can anyone help me...

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php');

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$session     = &JFactory::getSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use :

```
    //Joomla Stuff
    define( '_JEXEC', '1' );
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

    $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

    /**
    * INITIALISE THE APPLICATION
    *
    * NOTE :
    */
    // set the language
    $mainframe->initialise();

    JPluginHelper::importPlugin('system');

    // trigger the onAfterInitialise events
    JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterInitialise') : null;
    $mainframe->triggerEvent('onAfterInitialise');
    // End Joomla Stuff
```

Comment: I tried this also still it's not working....
Please help me, it's urgent..

Comment: If there is any other way to accomplished this.Plz tell me...